# Having a problem with placement-new!

Tags: c++, constructor, new-operator

I am having a problem placing an instance of my reference-counting Pointer`<Type>` class into my Array class. Using the debugger, it seems that the constructor is never called (which messes up the reference-count and causes a segfault down the line)!

My push_back function is:

```
void push_back(const T& element)
{
    if (length >= max)
        reallocate(max > 0 ? max * 2 : 1);

    new (&data[length]) T(element);
    ++length;
}
```

The reference-count is the same before new is called as after. I'm very sure this is the problem, but I can't figure out why the constructor wouldn't be called. Additionally Pointer::Pointer(...) compiles whether it takes a Pointer`<T>`& or a const Pointer`<T>`& (huh?), and has the problem regardless as well!

Maybe there are some details on placement new I am not taking into account. If anyone has some thoughts, they'd be much appreciated!

edit: [as requested, a relevant excerpt from Pointer]

```
// ...
private:
    T* p;

public:
    //! Constructor
    Pointer()
        : p(0)
    {

    }

    //! Copy Constructor
    template<class X> Pointer(Pointer<X>& other)
        : p(other.getPointer())
    {
        if (p)
            p->incrementRef();
    }

    //! Constructor (sets and increments p)
    Pointer(T* p)
        : p(p)
    {
        if (p)
            p->incrementRef();
    }

    //! Destructor (decrements p)
    ~Pointer()
    {
        if (p)
            p->decrementRef();
    }
// ...
```

I've also implemented operator = for Pointer`<T>`& and `T*`, as well as operator -> and operator `T*`

Comment: Do you have copy constructor for your Pointer, or did compiler made one for you?

Comment: Maybe some details regarding Pointer<T> implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment and your code are out of sync:

```
//! Copy Constructor
template<class X> Pointer(Pointer<X>& other)
```

A constructor generated from a class template is not a *copy constructor* (there's a footnote in 12.8 [class.copy] that clarifies this), so won't prevent the compiler from generating a *copy constructor* for you. This generated constructor will be a better match for a standard copy as non-template functions are preferred to template functions in overload resolution.

It appears that you need to write an explicit *copy constructor* in your pointer class to get the desired effect.

Comment: @Bailey, ah! This is likely the problem! I need a function that takes a Pointer<A> to be able to take a Pointer<B> if B inherits from A though! How can I accomplish this at the same time? Writing both templated and non-templated versions of this function is ambiguous for the compiler...

Comment: It shouldn't be ambiguous. Have you tried it? Either the copy constructor is a match, in which case it beats the template constructor for the reasons I mentioned above, or it isn't a match, in which case the template constructor should pick up the other valid cases.

Comment: @Bailey: Thanks! That was the solution. I could have sworn I tried it before and got an error regarding some ambiguity...

Answer (score 2):

According to docs constructor should be called... Few things you can check:

To test pointer:

```
Pointer<int> p1(new int);
Pointer<int> p2(p1); // Does this call constructor properly?
```

To test array:

```
Array<std::string> array;
std::string str("bla");
array.push_back(str); // Does this call string's constructor
```

That's what fails, right?

```
Array<Pointer<int> > array;
Pointer<int> p1(new int);
array.push_back(p1);
```

If all else fails, you can always do this to surely invoke copy constructor or operator=

```
T* t = new (&data[length]) T();
*t = element;
```

Comment: @Eugene: The same problem occurs with operator T*() removed, but i'm still curious what the problem would be with implementing that...

Comment: @Eugene: I went through your tests for Pointer and Array and both worked fine. When I tried an Array of Strings, it entered my String's copy constructor (Pointer's is posted in my edit above) :

 //! Copy Constructor
 String(const String<T>& other)
                : data(0), max(0), length(0)
 {
  *this = other;
 }

Comment: Implicit conversion might easily end up bypassing your reference counter (there is a reason boost smart pointers don't implement it).

Comment: Actually you are using deep reference counting, so it is not as bad.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your Pointer class here.
I would think that the T in this class is Pointer ? 
If so is the code supposed to do:
new (&data[length]) Pointer(element);

which I'm having a hard time understanding..

why not just do:
data[length] = element;
I'm assuming data[length] is Pointer